# JQuery: Clone when moved offscreen

Tags: jquery, clone, append, html-lists, easyslider

I have a slider and the slider stretches 100% of the page. I wish to programmatically clone the first element as it leaves the screen and place it at the end, or rather, just move it, without a clone to keep the memory low. Could somebody point me in the right direction to do this?

I'm currently using EasySlider 1.7

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for

```
var hold = $(element);
var parent = hold.parent();
hold.detach();
parent.append(hold);
```

or

```
var hold=$(element);
hold.position(hold.parent().children().length);
```

*not sure about the last one though probably need some more test :p*

Comment: yeah but what function tests for if the image is off the page

Comment: then you are probably looking for $(element).offset() and $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: or $(window).scrollLeft() in the other case :p